# Creating a Socket Server

Tags: sockets

I need to create a socket server that can receive and send messages.  It doesn't need to do much processing. I already have a web server.  The current languages I know are PHP, Python, and Node.js, but I am willing to learn other languages.  This has to be able to run on the Raspberry PI and have many clients at once.  I am using this along with HTML5's websocket api so hopefully they are compatible.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I suggest you try it and post any concrete problems you have here. At the moment this is not a real question.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache mina](https://mina.apache.org/) would be a great choice. it is a wonderful socket framework.

`It provides an abstract event-driven asynchronous API over various transports such as TCP/IP and UDP/IP via Java NIO.`

Answer (score 0):

PHP.NET has a complete example of a socket server and client:

http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php